# Date range between TimeStamp

Tags: timestamp, between

Why result difference

Q1

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABC where CONVERT(DATE, TimeStamp, 101) between   '2013-10-01'  and '2013-10-31'
```

Q2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABC where TimeStamp between   '2013-10-01'  and '2013-10-31'
```

Q2 ignore result of date 31st but when converting date format its showing all of the result including 31st date

Comment: What **database** is this, and what are the **datatypes** involved (e.g. the `TimeStamp` column)

Answer (score 0):

Since your between statement doesn't include a time for the end date it will only return values up to 10/31/2013 00:00:00.000. Any time after that would not match.

However in your first query you are chopping off the time of the values in the timestamp field, so any value with any time on 10/31/2013 will be included.